# Mysql SELECT process information (percent complete)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-administration

Can someone help me with the following:

I'm trying to get the mysql process information (percent complete) to show it to the user in a processbar.
I already tried:

```
   SELECT percent_complete  
   FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s  
   INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r  
   ON s.session_id = r.session_id
```

But i keep getting the error that the table sys.dm_exec_sessions s  doesnt exist.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that's a SQL Server table, not MySQL.

Comment: question's unclear and as to what the relation to php is also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments to the question, `sys.dm_exec_requests` view is for [ms sql server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx), it does not exists in MySQL. This is why you get the table not found error.

In MySQL from v5.7.9 the following [4 views in the sys schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema-progress-reporting.html) provide progress information on long lasting processes:

- [processlist](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-processlist.html) (progress field)
- [session](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-session.html)
- [x$processlist](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-processlist.html) (progress field)
- [x$session](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-session.html)

The 4 views are very similar, just the session related views filter out background processes to display only user sessions, while the processlist views list the background ones as well. In all views the `progress` field returns the progress in % (if possible).

```
SELECT progress  
FROM sys.session s
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I Was Looking For